# What methods exist for capturing stdout into a buffer that is automatically cleared on read?

Tags: pipe, fifo, ipc

I want to store the stdout from a process into a buffer and have the buffer emptied once read, FIFO style.

I know that I can pipe the stdout, but the pipe/file will keep growing and contain data that I have already read. I just want the fresh data.

```
command > named_pipe &
```

Are there any other inbuilt methods, similar to a buffer in a network socket, that I can redirect data to?

Comment: What is "fresh data"?

Comment: @AndyDalton Data that I have not already read/processed. Using the socket analogy I can perform a read which empties the buffer. Data that I have not read is still in the buffer.

Comment: What you just described is also the semantics of a named pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how named pipes don't solve your problem.  This example uses two shell interfaces, `shell_1` and `shell_2`.  I indent I/O from/to `shell_2` more than that of `shell_1` to try to differentiate what I/O is occurring from which shell.

```
$ mkfifo my_pipe
(shell_1) $ echo hi > my_pipe # Blocks waiting for a reader
    (shell_2) $ cat my_pipe # Unblocks shell_1
    hi
    (shell_2) $ cat my_pipe # blocks -- does not print "hi" again
(shell_1) $ echo bye > my_pipe # Unblocks shell_2
    bye # Printed by shell_2
```

Comment: You're completely right! Thanks for the example. I don't know what I was doing before, but it's now working as expected.